# SQL(query) error or missing database even after Database and Table is created

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

In my 1st Activity (Room Activity) i am displaying list of Rooms entered in database. In same screen i added button to create more rooms. In CreateRoom activity we can add more rooms and after creating it will come back to 1st activity. Everything works perfect till now. If click on any room it will open Appliance activity with list of appliance But when i click on any of the room crashing app. If database or table is not created then it should also crash on Room Activity, why it is crashing on only Appliance activity?

**Room Activity**

```
public class Rooms extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> roomList;
DBOpenHelper db;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rooms);

    db = new DBOpenHelper(this);
    roomList = db.GetRooms();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRooms);
    final ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, roomList, R.layout.roomlist, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.txtRoomName});
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Rooms.this, Appliance.class);
            intent.putExtra("roomname", listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    db = new DBOpenHelper(this);
    roomList = db.GetRooms();
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, roomList, R.layout.roomlist, new String[]{"name"}, new int[]{R.id.txtRoomName});
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
}
```

**CreateRoom**

```
public class CreateRoom extends AppCompatActivity {

int i = 1;
EditText editText;
List<EditText> ed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_room);

    final LinearLayout textLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.textLayout);
    Button btnAddRoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddRoom);
    Button btnCreateRoom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateRoom);
    final EditText txtRoomname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.r1);
    ed = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    btnAddRoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i += 1;
            editText = new EditText(CreateRoom.this);
            editText.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            editText.setHint("Room Name" + i);
            editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            textLayout.addView(editText);
            ed.add(editText);
        }
    });

    btnCreateRoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DBOpenHelper db = new DBOpenHelper(CreateRoom.this);
            if (txtRoomname.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                db.addRoom(txtRoomname.getText().toString());
            }
            int i = 0;
            while (i< ed.size()) {
                if (ed.get(i).getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    db.addRoom(ed.get(i).getText().toString());
                }
                i++;
            }
            finish();
        }
    });

}
 }
```

**DBOpenHelper**

```
public class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DB_NAME = "Automation";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Room";
private static final String ROOM_NAME = "roomname";
private static final String TB_NAME = "Appliance";
private static final String RM_NAME = "RmName";
private static final String APPLIANCE_NAME = "AppName";


public DBOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String QUERY_CREATE_ROOM = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + ROOM_NAME + " TEXT"+ ")";
    String QUERY_CREATE_APPLIANCE = "CREATE TABLE " + TB_NAME + " (" + RM_NAME + " TEXT, "+ APPLIANCE_NAME + " TEXT"+")";
    db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_ROOM);
    db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_APPLIANCE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TB_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

void addRoom(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ROOM_NAME, name);
    long newRowID = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}



public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetRooms(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> roomList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT roomname FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String, String> room = new HashMap<>();
        room.put("name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ROOM_NAME)));
        roomList.add(room);
    }
    return roomList;
}

void addApplance(String roomname, String appliancename){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(RM_NAME, roomname);
    contentValues.put(APPLIANCE_NAME, appliancename);
    long newRowID = db.insert(TB_NAME, null, contentValues);
    db.close();
}



public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> GetAppliance(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> applianceList = new ArrayList<>();
    String query = "SELECT AppName FROM " + TB_NAME + " WHERE RmNAme=" + name;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String, String> appliance = new HashMap<>();
        appliance.put("appliance", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(APPLIANCE_NAME)));
        applianceList.add(appliance);
    }
    return applianceList;
}
}
```

**ApplianceActivity** - where app crashing

```
public class Appliance extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> applianceList;
DBOpenHelper db;
String room;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appliance);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String r = intent.getStringExtra("roomname");
    room = r.replace("{name=", "").replace("}","");

    if (getSupportActionBar()!= null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(room);
    }

    db = new DBOpenHelper(this);
    applianceList = db.GetAppliance(room);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAppliance);
    final ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, applianceList, R.layout.roomlist, new String[]{"appliance"}, new int[]{R.id.txtRoomName});
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    db = new DBOpenHelper(this);
    applianceList = db.GetAppliance(room);
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, applianceList, R.layout.roomlist, new String[]{"appliance"}, new int[]{R.id.txtRoomName});
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}

 }
```

**Error Log**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.smiles.automation, PID: 24981
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.smiles.automation/com.smiles.automation.Appliance}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: G (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AppName FROM Appliance WHERE RmNAme=G
              #################################################################
              Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
              Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                (no such column: G (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AppName FROM Appliance WHERE RmNAme=G)
              #################################################################
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: G (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AppName FROM Appliance WHERE RmNAme=G
              #################################################################
              Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
              Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
                (no such column: G (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AppName FROM Appliance WHERE RmNAme=G)
              #################################################################
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1062)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:627)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1410)
                  at com.smiles.automation.DBOpenHelper.GetAppliance(DBOpenHelper.java:83)
                  at com.smiles.automation.Appliance.onCreate(Appliance.java:39)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                    ... 9 more
```

My Room Activity and Appliance Activity is almost similar but why it is crashing only in Appliance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: G
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AppName FROM Appliance WHERE
>   RmNAme=G

You are getting [**`SQLiteException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException)

> A SQLite exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing
>   or execution.

You should **`RECTIFY`** your **`SELECT`** Statement.

- You need a **`single quote`**.

Try this

```
"SELECT AppName FROM " + TB_NAME + " WHERE RmNAme ='" + name + "'";
```

Then **`Uninstall App`** and Run again.

Answer (score 0):

> no such column: G (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT AppName FROM Appliance WHERE RmNAme=G)

At a minimum quote the `G` value

```
String query = "SELECT AppName FROM " + TB_NAME + " WHERE RmNAme= '" + name + "'";
```

But it would be better of to use a prearedStatement of similar

Comment: Sir, Set ' instead of `.

Comment: @Acg Sorry there was a typo, please try again. If there is an error please show the error message